# Finding CDF of random variable $X$ given $X(\omega)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, cumulative-distribution-functions

The problem I have been presented with is as follows:

Let $\Omega = (0,1)$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}(\Omega) $, $P = \lambda \text{ (Lebesgue measure)}$. Assume $X(\omega) = \omega^{-3}$. Prove $X$ is a random variable, and find the CDF and PDF for $X$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $A = \{ \omega \in (0,1) \text{ } \vert \text{ } a < X(\omega) < b\}$ where $0 < a < b$. We may rewrite $A$ as
$$ A = \{ \omega \in (0,1) \text{ } \vert \text{ } a < \omega^{-3} < b\} $$
which is to say
$$A = \{ \omega \in (0,1) \text{ } \vert \text{ } b^{-\frac{1}{3}} < \omega < a^{-\frac{1}{3}} \}$$
which is a Borel set in $\mathcal{F}$.
Thus $P(A) = a^{-\frac{1}{3}} - b^{-\frac{1}{3}}$. Therefore, $X$ is a random variable (I understand this is quite hand-wavy and leaves a lot to be desired, but this is the final line in similar "proofs" from our lecture).

This is where I struggle. Is the CDF for $X$ just simply $F_X(u) = u^{-\frac{1}{3}}$, giving the PDF for $X$ as $f_X(u) = \frac{1}{3} u^{-\frac{4}{3}}$? I thought this was the solution until I realized $\lim_{u \to \infty} F_X(u) \neq 1$, which should equal $1$ for any CDF by definition. Where is my understanding failing?

Comment: Relate $P(X < x)$ directly to $P(\omega < \omega_0)$, but be careful of the direction. Note that $\omega = 1/2$ corresponds to $X = 8$, $\omega = 1/3$ corresponds to $X = 27$, etc.

Comment: Draw a sketch of $X$ on $(0,1)$, draw a horizontal line for some $y=\alpha$ and guess what $P[X \le \alpha]$ is.

Comment: Clearly the $F_X$ does not pass muster. If $u \to \infty$ you should have $F_X(u) \to 1$.

Comment: Thank you all for your hints. I think I have arrived at the solution, please correct me if I am wrong:

For $u \geq 1$, we have

\begin{align}
F_X(u) &= P(X \leq u) \nonumber\\
&= P(\{ \omega \in (0,1) : \omega^{-3} \leq u \}) \nonumber\\
&= P(\{ \omega \in (0,1) : u^{-\frac{1}{3}} \leq \omega \}) \nonumber\\
&= 1 - P(\{ \omega \in (0,1) : \omega \leq u^{-\frac{1}{3}} \}) \nonumber\\
&= 1 - u^{-\frac{1}{3}} \nonumber
\end{align}

Comment: @BrianTung Does this seem correct?

Comment: I think it is. You may want to post this on your own question as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the provided hints, I think I have created a full answer:

**First:** Let $A = \{ w \in \Omega = (0,1) \text{ } \vert \text{ } a < X(\omega) < b \}$ where $0 < a < b$. From $a < X(\omega) = \omega^{-3}$, we have $w < a^{-\frac{1}{3}}$. Similarly, from $X(\omega) = \omega^{-3} < b$, we have $b^{-\frac{1}{3}} < \omega$. Thus, we have that
$$ A = \{ w \in \Omega = (0,1) \text{ } \vert \text{ } b^{-\frac{1}{3}} < \omega < a^{-\frac{1}{3}} \}  = (b^{-\frac{1}{3}},a^{-\frac{1}{3}})  $$
Hence, $A$ is an interval, and any interval is a Borel set in $\mathcal{F}$. Therefore, $X$ is a measurable function.

**Second:** For $u \geq 1$, we have
\begin{align}
                    F_X(u)  &=  P(X \leq u) \nonumber\\
                            &=  P( \{ w \in (0,1) \text{ } \vert \text{ } \omega^{-3} < u \} ) \nonumber\\
                            &=  P( \{ w \in (0,1) \text{ } \vert \text{ } u^{-\frac{1}{3}} \leq \omega  \} ) \nonumber\\
                            &=  1 - P( \{ w \in (0,1) \text{ } \vert \text{ } \omega \leq u^{-\frac{1}{3}}  \} ) \nonumber\\
                            &=  1 - u^{-\frac{1}{3}}\nonumber
                \end{align}
Thus, the CDF for $X$ is given as
$$ 
                    F_X(u) = \begin{cases} 
                                0 & \text{ for } u < 1 \\
                                1 - u^{-\frac{1}{3}} & \text{ for } u \geq 1 \\
                    \end{cases}
                $$
From this expression, we may find the PDF of $X$ as
$$ 
                    f_X(u) = \begin{cases} 
                                0 & \text{ for } u < 1 \\
                                \frac{1}{3} u^{-\frac{4}{3}} & \text{ for } u \geq 1 \\
                    \end{cases}
                $$